# How to debug a cshtml file in visual studio/ set the executable file

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, razor

I am new to the .net environment.  I have used other ide's like webstorm.  Usually, I would just find a file and debug it in Chrome, but since the file is part of a base layout it seems to be in various places.

[image]

I am getting a warning after I try to run the debugger.   It seems that I have to make some changes to running my files.  Not sure if the error cannot read what I am trying to do or if there is a way to set the executable file.

[image]

Comment: Since it is javascript you want to debug, why not move it into its own file and let the browser load it with a script-tag? Then you can easily debug it as usual in the browser

Comment: Regarding the exception; either your environment isn't setup to start in a webserver (iisexpress?), or your solution has multiple projects and tje wrong one is set as the start project. Right-click on the web project and select "Set as startup".

Comment: @MattiasÅslund  went to my main project and set that as "startup".  I am getting a different kind of error that is still blocking me though "The breakpoint will not be hit no executable code is associated with this line

Comment: No that's right - the javascript isn't executable by Visual Studio - it's javascript. So back to my first comment :)